# PHP Get the value of $n after foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to write a XLS file.
But I need a way to automatically set the number of the cells based on the results I got from the DB.
This is why I am using an incremental `$n`.
The problem is that all works in the first `foreach` but in the second one the value of the previous `$n` is lost and it overwrites the previous cells.
How do I keep the value of the incremented `$n` outside of the `foreach` loop?
This is what I have done so far:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A7', 'Tot number unique visits per device:');
    $n=7;
    foreach ($visits_by_device as $key) {
        $n = $n++;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, $key["device_type"]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$n, $key["tot"]);
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, 'Tot number Unique Visits per Date:');
    foreach ($visits_by_date as $key) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, $key["date"]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$n, $key["tot"]);
    }
```

Comment: Simply increment `$n++` before starting second foreach.

Comment: There is no reason why `$n` should lose it's value in the code above.

Comment: Oh I think I completely misunderstood you...just ignore my answer then...lol

Comment: @Carlo Giovannelli How does puttin the `$n++` above the second foreach solves your problem? The second foreach will overwrite the same key every loop.. I.E: First loop runs 8 times, then you set `$n` to 9 and then the second loop will affect only the cells `A9` and `B9`..

Answer (score 1):

Simple...just give it a seperate variable, such as $k in this example

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A7', 'Tot number unique visits per device:');
$n=7;
$k=$n
foreach ($visits_by_device as $key) {
    $n = $n++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, $key["device_type"]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$n, $key["tot"]);
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, 'Tot number Unique Visits per Date:');
foreach ($visits_by_date as $key) {
 $k = $k++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$k, $key["date"]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$k, $key["tot"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `$n++` to the beginning of the second loop to continue the count of `$n`.

```
$n = 7;
foreach ($visits_by_device as $key) {
    $n++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, $key["device_type"]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$n, $key["tot"]);
}

$n = 7; add this line if you want to count from 7 again. Remove it to continue counting.
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, 'Tot number Unique Visits per Date:');
foreach ($visits_by_date as $key) {
    $n++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$n, $key["date"]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$n, $key["tot"]);
}
```

Comment: I mightve misunderstood, but doesn't he want the second loop to also start at 7??  So that the cells match up?

Comment: If that's the case then he should put `$n = 7;` above the second for loop.

Comment: Yes, but $n is coming from the database so he wont know the value, hence why I assigned $n to $k and just used $k, in code below...

Comment: I would put the value form the db into an variable like `start_num` or something and use that to assing the `$n` variable.

Comment: Well....I think you had it right before, as I just read his comment above, and it looks like the way you had it, was the way he wanted it....the $n++ in the second loop........I thought he was having an issue with the lining up of cells which is why he needed to reset the number.....but I misunderstood I think

Answer (score 0):

Use the `static` keyword to keep the value of variable like this:

```
static $n=7;
```

This will keep the previous value and will not lost the value.